# React Native fetch abortController - figuring out abort reason

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm in need of implementing following features for network/http client using `fetch` API.

1. Timeout
2. Also abort a previous request when user make multiple requests.

I was able to implement both using the abortController. But on the case of "Timeout" (no 1), I want to catch the abort and show a proper error message with "retry" option.

But when I wrap my network request inside try catch, I can't distinguish between above 1 and 2 cases. Cause both abort are thrown with same exception name/message.

The web implementation does support passing a "reason" into the `abort()` call. But looks like reactNative doesn't have that implemented ( Using react-native 0.63.3 )

```js
async function request(url, abortController) {
      // Manually timing out, as I did not find any support for timeout on react-native
      const timeoutRef = setTimeout(() => abortController.abort(), 90000); // CASE 1 : Timeout abort

      return await fetch(url,
      {
        signal: controller.signal
      })
}

var abortController = null;
var requestPending  = false;

async function searchWebsite(searchQuery) {
    // If there is already pending requesting - we cancel that previous
    // pending request.
    if ( abortController && !controller.signal.aborted && requestPending) {
        abortController.abort(); // CASE 2 : abort previous request
    }

    // Create a new request
    try {
        abortController = new AbortController();
        requestPending = true;
        let apiRequest = await request("http://someurl.com", abortController);

        // Do whatever with `apiRequest`
        
        requestPending = false;

    } catch(e) {
        requestPending = false;
        if (e.name == 'AbortError') {
        // HERE I'M STRUGGLING WITH
        // figure out how to distinguish between "timeout" and "previous request" abort 
        }
    }
}
```

How can I distinguish between different type of abortController abort on react-native?

Comment: You can avoid this problem totally by using axios (since it has timeout built in) instead of fetch. That way, you can be sure AbortError is for cancelling requests and not timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I was in this situation before and decided to move the cancellation logic to the async function itself instead of the fetch, and create another abort controller instance, then you can throw a different message based on which abort controller you used to abort the request, based on that message you'll know which abort controller caused the error (the cancellation)

Here is an example of what i did (in a react hook), but you should be able to apply the same logic and throw your own errors in whichever way you like

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (abortControllerCancel.current.signal.aborted) {
                    reject({
                        message: 'canceled',
                        reason: 'canceled',
                    });
                }
                if (abortControllerDuplicate.current.signal.aborted) {
                    reject({
                        message: 'canceled',
                        reason: 'duplicate',
                    });
                }
             

// the rest of the async function and resolving the promise


abortControllerCancel.current.signal.addEventListener(
                    'abort',
                    () => {
                        reject({
                            message: 'canceled',
                            reason: 'canceled',
                        });
                    }
                );
               
                abortControllerDuplicate.current.signal.addEventListener(
                    'abort',
                    () => {
                        reject({
                            message: 'canceled',
                            reason: 'duplicate',
                        });
                    }
                );
}
```